# KVM guest loses network connectivity after migration

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Environment CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

(libvirt-0.10.2-18.el6.x86_64)
- (kernel  2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64)

I have been experiencing issues with KVM guest loses network connectivity after migration from one host to another, migration is successful but my guest loses its network connectivity.

It only work, after restarting network service or rebooting the guest.

Any ideas on why its happening?

Comment: provide more info - network and guest settings on both hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of troubleshooting, I have tried Ubuntu 12.4 as a KVM host, with the same network configuration as the CentOS box, and I never had any issue with live migration and network connectivity.

I'm using libvirt 0.9.8 and kernel 3.5.0-26, not sure whats wrong with CentOS 6.3/6.4 maybe its a bug!

I'm a RHEL guy, and I'm sorry to switch to Ubuntu, but I guess I would have to stick to it for now.